# Grab what is after f1= but ignore \r\n and \n if they are present

Tags: python, python-2.7

Currently i use this:

```
a = re.search(r'(?<=f1=)(.*)',a)
```

to get the string after `f1=`.  But sometimes the string looks like this

```
 f1=Test String \r\n  or   f1=Test String \n
```

in other words if there is such thing as

```
\n or \r\n
```

i would like to avoid parsing them by mistake but usually they aren't present.

Comment: Why do you have `\r` in the string in the first place? Python uses only `\n` for linebreaks. And they aren't matched by `.*`. Also, you don't need a capturing group here, and you need to call `.group()` on the result to get a string. Are you really showing us your actual code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
a = re.search(r'(?<=f1=)(.*)', a.strip())
```

strip() will remove trailing spaces and line feeds.